# VBA Error 13 Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a line of cells in a sheet to a multicolumn listbox in a userform. The number of columns in the sheet also varies. I keep getting the error 'Type mismatch.' Stepping through my code I found that it occurs at the first .AddItem line. I found out that you cannot add multiple items with .AddItem. Is there another method to do this? I'm very new to vba. Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub GenerateButton_Click()
  Dim i As Long, counter As Long, counter_RA As Long, x As Integer
  Dim LastColRA As Long, LastColCP As Long


  LastColRA = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  LastColCP = Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


  'Check to make sure that enough items were selected
  For x = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(x) Then
      counter_RA = counter_RA + 1
      With TabData.DataTable
        .AddItem Sheets(Sheet1).Range(Cells(x + 2, 1), Cells(x + 2, LastColRA)).Text
      End With
    End If
  Next x

  For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
      counter = counter + 1
      With TabData.DataTable
        .AddItem Sheets(Sheet2).Range(Cells(i + 2, 1), Cells(i + 2, LastColCP)).Text
      End With
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues there. First, if you use the `Text` property of a multiple cell range, it will return `Null` unless all the cells contain the same text. Second, as you note, you cannot add an array in one go using `AddItem` - you need to add an item then loop to populate the columns, remembering that the indices are 0-based:

```
With TabData.DataTable
   .AddItem
   For n = 1 to LastColRA
      .List(.ListCount - 1, n - 1) = Sheet1.Cells(x + 2, n).Value
   next n
End With
```

Here's a version that will work with more than 10 columns:

```
Dim i As Long, counter As Long, counter_RA As Long, x As Long
Dim LastColRA As Long, LastColCP As Long
Dim vList()


LastColRA = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LastColCP = Sheet2.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


'Check to make sure that enough items were selected
For x = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox2.Selected(x) Then
        counter_RA = counter_RA + 1
        ReDim Preserve vList(1 To LastColRA, 1 To counter_RA)
        For i = 1 To LastColRA
            vList(i, counter_RA) = Sheet1.Cells(x + 2, i).Value
        Next i
    End If
Next x
For x = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(x) Then
        counter_RA = counter_RA + 1
        ReDim Preserve vList(1 To LastColRA, 1 To counter_RA)
        For i = 1 To LastColRA
            vList(i, counter_RA) = Sheet2.Cells(x + 2, i).Value
        Next i
    End If
Next x

With TabData.DataTable
    .ColumnCount = LastColRA
    .Column = vList
End With
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I am getting Error 13 again for the .List line.

Comment: How many columns do you have? You're limited to 10 with `AddItem`. Also, are there any error values in your cells?

Comment: As of now, there are 5 columns I am dealing with. But in the future I hope to be able to use this tool with many more. There are no error values. All of the columns have only text in them. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just spotted a stupid error in the code - try the revised version please. I'll put up a version that will work with more than 10 columns in a minute.

Comment: Another question. As you can see in my original code I am pulling from two separate sets of data and putting them into one list. I duplicated your code for both sets. Only data from one set is being listed. Stepping through, I can see that it is going through the code correctly. My guess is that it is overwriting whatever was pulled from the first set. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Liz I've updated to show how it should look for the combined list.

Comment: Now I'm getting subscript out of range at 'Redim..' in the second part. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually now I am getting the same thing as before. Just the portion of data pulled from the second part of the code is displayed

Comment: It works for me - at least, it populates the control based only on the selected items at the time of clicking the button. In other words, it replaces any previous items.

Comment: Ok works for me now. I had a problem when I used two separate counters rather than one. Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!